# How to use Datatable in inertia vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using Inertia to build my application. When it comes to handling the datatable in my Inertia Vue.js application, how can I handle it? What is the best idea?

```
mounted() {
   $(this.$refs.table).DataTable({
     data: this.data,
     columns: [
       { title: 'ID', data: 'id' },
       { title: 'Name', data: 'name' },
     ]
   });
 }
```

Comment: I need more code ? What is that dollar sign ? and why's it wrapped in backtick ? You use single file component right ?

Comment: initially i want to render the datatable. examples show the dollar sign. do u have any other idea to implemet datatable with customer filters

Comment: You're using single file component right ? just render the table first. I have to see your data structure